# Extract substring from string in postgresql between an end delimiter and its previous motif

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm really struggling on this one :

I have some extradata in a postgresql db in which a number matters.

Exemple:

- `{"code_partenaire":"welcome","sous_statut_abc":"1","statut_alpha":"blabla"}`
- `{"code_partenaire":"code33","sous_statut_def":"1782","statut_alpha":"blablabla"}`
- `{"code_partenaire":"222","sous_statut_ghei":"17","statut_alpha":"blablaa"}`

I would like to extract the character between
`","statut_alpha"` and its previous `":"`

Because there is the number i'm looking for.

Do you have an idea ?

Output should be

- 1
- 1782
- 17

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: does number occur in any other places like front or back of the column or just the place you specified?

Comment: this part `"sous_statut_abc"` in every row are different ? talk about a,b,c,d,e,f...

Comment: yes it's different in most of the lines. We cannot refer to this ... Before the number the only thing that is common is,
":"
but there are others before.

Comment: @Sund'er yes, there could be number in other places too.

Comment: need to output the number that matches these two conditions (1) before : ","statut_alpha" (2) after the last ":" before ","statut_alpha"

Comment: @Madmaxoo  what is the column data type jsonb or varchar?

Comment: @Sund'er varchar :)

Answer (score 0):

For the output you given , the substring is tedious process , with the conditions
(1) before : ","statut_alpha"
for this used the reverse string and find the last position of  ":"
(2) after the last ":" before ","statut_alpha"

```
create table substdata (datac varchar(300));
insert into substdata values ('{"code_partenaire":"welcome","sous_statut_abc":"1","statut_alpha":"blabla"}');
insert into substdata values ('{"code_partenaire":"code33","sous_statut_def":"1782","statut_alpha":"blablabla"}');
insert into substdata values ('{"code_partenaire":"222","sous_statut_ghei":"17","statut_alpha":"blablaa"}');



select    
  substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) 
,
  length( substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) ), (
  length( substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) )
   -  
 pOSITION('":"' in 
 reverse(
  substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac))
  ))) as minus 
  , 
substring (substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) 
  ,
  
  (
  length( substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) )
   -  
 pOSITION('":"' in 
 reverse(
  substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac))
  )))+2,( length( substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)) ))) as finresult 
 from substdata
```

OUTPUT:

```
substring   length  minus   finresult
{"code_partenaire":"welcome","sous_statut_abc":"1   49  47  1
{"code_partenaire":"code33","sous_statut_def":"1782     51  46  1782
{"code_partenaire":"222","sous_statut_ghei":"27     47  44  17
```

if the first condition is always in the third position in the string

you can use the unest with ordinally give rownumber and filter with it

```
select row_number() over(),t from (
  select
 row_number() over() as id ,t
  from substdata ,
  unnest(string_to_array(
  substring 
  (datac,0,
  POSITION('","statut_alpha"' IN datac)), '":"'))  
  WITH ORDINALITY As T ) as drt 

WHERE (id % 3) = 0
```

OUTPUT 2 :

```
row_number  t
1   1
2   1782
3   17
```

Comment: thanks. More complexe, but more general than what i just dropped .

Answer (score 0):

Found it out :)

```
split_part(extradata,'"',8)
```